# How to optimize nested reverse relations?

Tags: performance

I have the following situation:

A section called "membership" and a section called "member".
Within the "member" section I can choose one or more memberships.
Now I'd like to display all memberships with the reverse related members.

The output would look something like this:

```
membership 1
    member 1, member 2, member 3

membership 2
    member 2, member 4

membership 3
    member 1, member 5
```

How would I do this?

I have the following code, but it's very slow:

```
{# 

    Get all membership entries 

#}
{% set entries = craft.entries({
    section: 'membership',
    order: 'cf_membershipShorthand',
}) %}

{% for entry in entries %}
    <h2><a class="external" href="{{ entry.cf_membershipLink }}">{% if entry.cf_membershipShorthand %}{{ entry.cf_membershipShorthand }} – {% endif %}{{ entry.title }}</a></h2>
    {# 

        Get the related members entries

    #}
    {% set members = craft.entries({
            section: 'member',
            relatedTo: entry,
        })
    %}
    {% if members|length %}
        {% for member in members %}
            {% set image = member.cf_ma_asset[0] ?? null %}
            {% if image|length %}
                {% set imageParams = { width: 30, height: 30 } %}
                <figure class="mini_portrait">
                    <a href="{{ member.getUrl() }}" title="{{ member.title }}"><img class="mini_portrait_image" src="{{ image.getUrl(imageParams) }}" alt="Portrait {{ image.title }}"></img></a>
                </figure>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I even tried to eager load the related members entries, but, to my surprise, that even added queries.

I must be on the wrong path. Could anyone enlighten me?

Thanks

Update to my question: 
I know how to eager load the related entries:

```
{% set member = craft.entries({
        section: 'member',
        relatedTo: entry,
        with: [
            ['cf_ma_asset', { withTransforms: [{ width: 30, height: 30 }] }],
        ]
    })
%}
```

To my surprise that adds queries, but is much faster...

Answer (score 1):

There’s a lot going on here. Let’s first work out the outline of your algorithm, and therefore where things could be improved.

- Query and iterate memberships

  - Query and iterate members

    - Query first asset

      - Get asset transform

*Note: Every time a transform is used, Craft first has to check whether the transform has been generated ([from the docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/eager-loading-elements#eager-loading-image-transform-indexes))*

As you can see, there are multiple levels of nested relations going on. You’ve mentioned using eager-loading already, but it is definitely beneficial here. One of the cool things Craft can do is eager-load nested relations.

Have you tried something like this?

```
{% set memberships = craft.entries({
    section: 'membership',
    order: 'cf_membershipShorthand',
    with: [
        '{relatedMembersField}.cf_ma_asset'
    ]
}) %}

{% for membership in memberships %}
    {% for member in membership.{relatedMembersField} %}
        {% set image = member.cf_ma_asset[0] ?? null %}
        {% set imageParams = { width: 30, height: 30 } %}

        {% if image %}
            {# Output image with transform #}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

*Where {relatedMembersField} is the handle of your entries field.*

Comment: Hello Stuart. Thanks a lot for your answer but I think you misunderstood my problem. I don't have a {relatedMembersField} within the memberships section. The relations are made within the members section and I want to get the members with a REVERSE relation. Maybe I'll have to get the members and memberships entries independently and somehow merge them... but I don't know how you'd do this...